# Phonegap Blackberry app not signing

Tags: exception, cordova, blackberry

I am building a phonegap app for blackberry. It runs fine in the emulator but when i try to sign the project using command line so that i can run it on an actual device it gives me the following exception occurs.

I googled it , it seems i have to use preverify tool and verify my jar file. But i dont have a jar file of my project, its just folders. Please help me out with this.

```
[INFO]                  Parsing command line options
[INFO]                  Parsing bbwp.properties
[INFO]                  Validating application archive
[INFO]                  Parsing config.xml
[WARNING]               Failed to find a <feature> element
[WARNING]               Failed to find the <author> element
[INFO]                  Populating application source
[INFO]                  Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application
Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.
Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.
Exported static routine: .main(String[]) is multiply defined.
net.sf.antcontrib.AntContribVersion: Error!: Missing stack map in: <init> at lab
el: 30
[ERROR]                 RAPC exception occurred
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i only found the solution. The problem was that the zip file was in C:\ drive, and windows was not allowing the SDK to access it because of UAC. 
Nevertheless found this silly solution after 2 days of trial and error. Silly me